# Calculating the size of an Array pack struct format in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pack

In the case of e.g. `ddddd`, `d` is the native format for the system, so I can't know exactly how big it will be.

In python I can do:

```
import struct
print struct.calcsize('ddddd')
```

Which will return `40`.

How do I get this in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a built-in way to do this, but I've had success with this small function when I know I'm dealing with only numeric formats:

```
  def calculate_size(format)
    # Only for numeric formats, String formats will raise a TypeError
    elements = 0
    format.each_char do |c|
      if c =~ /\d/
        elements += c.to_i - 1
      else
        elements += 1
      end
    end
    ([ 0 ] * elements).pack(format).length
  end
```

This constructs an array of the proper number of zeros, calls pack() with your format, and returns the length (in bytes). Zeros work in this case because they're convertible to each of the numeric formats (integer, double, float, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a shortcut but you can just pack one and ask how long it is:

```
length_of_five_packed_doubles = 5 * [1.0].pack('d').length
```

By the way, a ruby array combined with the [pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002222) method appears to be functionally equivalent to python's struct module. Ruby pretty much copied perl's `pack` and put them as methods on the `Array` class.